# Is there a way to parse and sort dates on rows?

Tags: shell, date, sort

If you have a file with rows sorted in this order(oldest to most recent):

```
<2021-05-10 Mon> <2021-06-04 Fri> <2021-07-04 Sun> <2021-08-01 Sun> ...
<2021-05-10 Mon> <2021-06-04 Fri> <2021-07-22 Thu> <2021-08-11 Wed> ...
<2021-05-10 Mon> <2021-06-04 Fri> <2021-07-18 Sun> <2021-08-01 Sun> ... 
...
```

Is there any shell utility for parsing and sorting the dates order(from  most recent to the oldest) in a row only:

```
<2021-08-01 Sun> <2021-07-04 Sun> <2021-06-04 Fri> <2021-05-10 Mon> ...
<2021-08-11 Wed> <2021-07-22 Thu> <2021-06-04 Fri> <2021-05-10 Mon> ... 
<2021-08-01 Sun> <2021-07-18 Sun> <2021-06-04 Fri> <2021-05-10 Mon> ...
...
```

Generic approach is appreciated as well.

Comment: @jsotola it's dates, yes

Comment: Do you need to sort them at all? As they already are sorted I mean. From the looks of things you want to reverse the order of fields enclosed in `<DATA>` - but there might be times you need to sort as well? – That's what you mean by *generic approach* as well perhaps?

Comment: When you say "_earliest_" it seems the corresponding examples show "_newest_" or "_most recent_". To me, "_earliest_" means the date furthest in the past.

Comment: @ibuprofen for "generic approach" I mean suggestions for libraries and is shell a good solution at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another `perl` approach:

```
$ perl -lpe '$_ = join " ", sort {$b cmp $a} /<.*?>/g' < file
<2021-08-01 Sun> <2021-07-04 Sun> <2021-06-04 Fri> <2021-05-10 Mon>
<2021-08-11 Wed> <2021-07-22 Thu> <2021-06-04 Fri> <2021-05-10 Mon>
<2021-08-01 Sun> <2021-07-18 Sun> <2021-06-04 Fri> <2021-05-10 Mon>
```

That extracts the `<...>` enclosed strings, sorts them in reverse (using byte-to-byte string comparison which should work OK for those YYYY-MM-DD dates), than prints them joined with one space. That does discard anything else in the input (including extra spacing or text not enclosed in `<...>`).

Here, as the input is in forward chronological order, you could also just use `reverse` to get it in reverse chronological order:

```
perl -lpe '$_ = join " ", reverse /<.*?>/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

One could (I believe) do:

```perl
perl -lpe '@F=split /</, $_ . " "; $_ = join "<", shift @F, sort {$b cmp $a} @F' sample.txt
```

Disadvantage: it adds an extra space at end of lines. One fix is to add `$_ =~ s/ $//` at end:

```perl
@F = split /</, $_ . " "; 
$_ = join "<", shift @F, sort {$b cmp $a} @F; 
$_ =~ s/ $//
```